# mysql count geo query

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm Having a hard time with this count query :

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS  `total`,
        ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 45.77447 ) ) 
               * COS( RADIANS( c.latitude ) ) 
               * COS( RADIANS( c.longitude ) - RADIANS( 4.82785 ) ) 
               + SIN( RADIANS( 45.77447 ) ) 
               * SIN( RADIANS( c.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, `r` . * 
FROM  `adverts` AS  `a` 
INNER JOIN  `users` AS  `u` ON a.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN  `location_city` AS  `c` ON a.location_id = c.city_id
INNER JOIN  `location_region` AS  `r` ON c.region_id = r.region_id
HAVING (distance <50)
LIMIT 1
```

This returns the total number of adverts in the table, not the total query count.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want the number of adverts satisfying `distance<50`? Then you need to use a sub-query, ie `SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT ... AS distance ... WHERE distance<50)`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. If you wish to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of adverts satisfying `distance<50`, where `distance` is a calculated field, you'll have to do a sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM
(SELECT .. AS distance
 ...
 WHERE distance < 50)
```

(By the way - I don't think it's valid MySQL to have a `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY`  (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't seem to add comments into posts (Still not sure how)

You could try add a

```
group by a.id
```

before LIMIT

.. however reading your post more, are you trying to get additional numbers into count such as users, location, and cities? If so you may need to result to sub-queries.

Comment: no, just the total number of results. Group by a.advert_id returns a total -> 1 for each row, right number of rows though. But not quite what I want

Comment: yea then looks like you'll need to look into a subquery, and use your supporting language to tally up the sum, mathemetical coffee summed it up nicely